# SoapUI global proxy testings doesn't work when executing tests

Tags: soapui

I have created a web test project using the SoapUi GUI (free version). I need a proxy to connect to the Internet. Therefore, I have set the proxy host and port in File->Preferences->Proxy Settings and made sure that it is enabled. The proxy is correct, because I can see the "soapUi Starter Page" properly and I can create SOAP project via WSDL successfully. But when I execute the test cases, it always shows the unknow host. It seems that the proxy settings doesn't take effect.

Anyone can help? I'm testing this public web service: http://www.webxml.com.cn/WebServices/WeatherWebService.asmx

Thanks

Comment: BTW: I'm using SOAPUI 4.5.0-Beta 1

Comment: I downloaded a pro trial version. This problem was solved. So, if you want to use soapui to access internet via proxy to run test cases, you have to buy Pro version.

Comment: Allan, can you find official statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

In short, use a older or newer version of SoapUI.
SoapUI was (is?) notoriously buggy concerning this proxy feature according to my own experience.
A huge number of users reported the same issue on their forum.
2 years ago, my workaround was to use a older and less buggy version of SoapUI.

Omar